# When can we just look at just the partial derivative of energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

I am reading a text about fluid mechanics and in the chapter about the (zero viscosity) Wuler equation this showed up:

> We consider now the kinetic energy and the internal energy of the system and assume
>   adiabatic conditions. The change in specific energy per volume of a fluid is ($ \epsilon $ is the internal energy per volume):
>   $$ { \partial \over \partial t} \left(  \rho { v^2 \over 2 } + \rho \epsilon \right) $$

I would like wo know why we can look at the partial derivative here?

I understand that due to Reynolds transport theorem we could conclude  **for the whole Volume** that for the energy density $\rho_E$:

$$ { {d \over d t} E } = \int_V { \partial \rho_E \over \partial t}  dV + \underbrace{\int_{\partial V} \rho_E  \vec v \;d \vec f}_{=0}$$
only the partial counts, we can assume a constant total energy in the system, but why would this hold for any volume?

Comment: That's just the change of some scalar you will call your energy with respect to time, the other parts of the equation will talk about the advection and source to energy. The partial derivative with respect to time, plus the advection define the lagrangian derivative which is the total time derivative. You might wish to review Eulerian verse lagrangian frame of references for fluids. The Reynolds transport theorem is the integral equivalent of the lagrangian derivative, and that term you said is zero isn't.

Comment: in a fluid the specific energy per volume will vary temporally and spatially, hence any derivative should be partial

Comment: But why? We look at total derivatives all the time. And my calculation at the top shows what we assume if we just say the time development is characterised by the partial derivative. Aswell normally taking the partial istead the total means we assume that the variables do not themselves depend on time, as you yourself said this is defenetly wrong here.

Comment: what I am saying is: your argument sounds like an argument to look at the total derivative to me, would you care to explain?